# Using Ajax in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to use high chart. I am new to high chart also new to jquery also. I was trying load categories and series into the line chart. This is the code which i am used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function getData(){
      alert('fff');
      $.ajax({
    url:"high_line_data.php",
    type:"POST",    
    success:function(resp){
      chart.series[0].setData(resp);
    }
      });
    }


        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25,
          events: {
               load: getData
          }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: []
        });
    }); 

        </script>
```

and php script

I am echoing the series  result as

```
name:'Test',
Data : '1,3,4,5'
```

How can I resolve this. Please help.

Comment: Resolve what? What is the problem?

Comment: Your `Data: '1,3,4,5'` is a string.  That's not going to work, should be a javascript array `Data: [1,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your string values with numbers. Obiously you can use JSON format to add points.

Related article about preprocessing data from PHP: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

parse the output of the php from text to array. highcharts also accepts a direct array of integers as input to plot the data.

hope this will be useful